# jQuery: How to make header and footer not scroll?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, scroll

I have a header and footer plus a listview in the main html5 body but the issue that I am having is that when the listView is large, it scrolls the whole page including the header.

what I am trying to achieve is to just make the listview scrollable and nothing else so that the header and footer is always visible.

Is this possible in html5/jquery?

edit:

Here is what I have tried.

```
<link href="src/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="src/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="" onclick="history.back(-1); return false;">Back</a>
            <h1>Claim Items</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <h3 style="margin-left:1em">The Demo Title</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="itemList" data-inset="true" data-scroll="true">
                <li><a href="#page2">1: demo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">2: demo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">3: demo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="fdfd.html">Add an Item</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="">Remove an Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Add comment</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try making the header and footer `position: fixed;` in the css

Comment: you need to use plugins iScroll or iScrollview.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are asking for a [fixed toolbar](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html):

In browsers that support CSS `position: fixed` (most desktop browsers, iOS5+, Android 2.2+, BlackBerry 6, and others), toolbars that use the "fixedtoolbar" plugin will be fixed to the top or bottom of the viewport, while the page content scrolls freely in between. In browsers that don't support fixed positioning, the toolbars will remain positioned in flow, at the top or bottom of the page.

To enable this behavior on a header or footer, add the `data-position="fixed`" attribute to a jQuery Mobile header or footer element.

Fixed header markup example:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```

Fixed footer markup example:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Footer!</h1>
</div>
```

---

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7zZEw/).

Comment: This particialy worked but has two issues. first issue is that the header dissapeares when scrolling and reappears when finished scrolling. i want it to be fixed at all time to give the impression that only the <div data-role="content> will scroll.

Comment: @jonney check the link to the documentation. It is using this approach to have fixed toolbar and its behaviour is the expected

Comment: Yes i checked that and it is not behaving as i intended to. let me post code

Comment: @jonney what browser are you using? It's working fine in Chrome

Comment: Safari. maybe thats the issue?

Comment: i just tried chrome using the code i just posted and same issue

Comment: maybe a css issue then? what could possibly making it auto hide when scrolling on the css?

Comment: @jonney But are you having the same issue with the demo?

Comment: I am using teh default jquery mobile css if that helps

Comment: Try to create a Fiddle that reproduces your issue, otherwise it's difficult to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="header1" data-tap-toggle="false" style="border-bottom:4px solid #f57122;">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

In my experience you need also to set data-tap-toggle to false, because you dont want the header to disappear if they click anywhere on the page. Also you need this data-id, if you have multiple pages you need the header on each page to have the same data-id so the jquery mobile will not replace current header of the active page.

EDIT:
If you experience blinking during page transitions on the actual device you have to add this to your index html also

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```